# My angular 4 app is getting slower when i have 700 elements in array in *ngFor

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

I have an array of objects (size 700) which is used in *ngFor. I am looking for something like [deferred loading](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat#deferred-loading). I am not updating any details in array object. Full array object is updated.

Comment: You may check something like this: https://codeburst.io/angular-2-simple-infinite-scroller-directive-with-rxjs-observables-a989b12d4fb1 or any generic ng2 infinite scroll

Comment: This is browser related. Every browser load this on his own way. Same for big table. Advice is use a pagination.

Comment: Does adding [trackBy](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5) improves performance? Also, i know in Angularjs you could set everything to a one-time-bind (with `::`), which removed all the bindings once they were evaluated. I have no idea how to do that in Angular 2+, but maybe you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have, by any chance, [expression binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) in the html code inside *ngFor? As it is re-evaluated on every event (e.g. mouse movement) maybe that causes the performance issue:

"Angular executes template expressions after every change detection cycle. Change detection cycles are triggered by many asynchronous activities such as promise resolutions, http results, timer events, keypresses and mouse moves."